# how to withdraw ether from a ERC20 token contract Address

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

[how to add withdraw function to get smart contract ether to my wallet](https://github.com/rohitsahu21/Token-Sale)

https://github.com/rohitsahu21/Token-Sale

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function withdraw() public {
    admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

The only address that will receive the ether is the admin, but anyone can execute the function (still the ether goes to the admin). To be sure that only you can execute it, you can do:

```
function withdraw() public {
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

Hope this helps.